# Error while upgrading a managed solution

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-2013, dynamics-crm-online

The import of a managed solution (as an upgrade to the existing solution) is failing with this unhelpful error.

***An error has occurred. Try this action again. If the problem continues, check the Microsoft Dynamics CRM Community for solutions or contact your organization's Microsoft Dynamics CRM Administrator. Finally, you can contact Microsoft Support.***

This error occurs on the import of `relationship` that is made between `Entitlement` entity as a primary one and a `custom activity` entity on `Regarding` field.

**Exported from:** Dynamics CRM 2013 On-premise with SP1 Update Rollup 1 (version 6.1.1.132)

**Imported To:** Dynamics CRM 2013 Online (version: 6.1.1.1847)

Please note that the same managed solution is upgrading on another on-premise test installation successfully.

If there is any way to get the trace files from the Dynamics CRM Online? Or any other way to investigate further?

### UPDATE

I have figured out something that I think might be the cause of this issue.

I search the net and came to know that `Entitlement entity is shipped with Service Pack 1`. It means that at the time of shipment of our product's earlier version the Entitlement entity was not present in the Dynamics CRM online system and hence we still can't find the relation `'Entitlement_xxx_customactivity'` in our online install.

While we are going to update the solution with the newer version of our product (that was exported with the SP1 Update Rollup 1 installed), this is causing error while importing the same `'Entitlement_xxx_customactivity'`

If this could be the case, please suggest something to resolve.

Comment: Tracing is not available on CRM Online, but this sounds like an issue which should be discussed with Support

Answer (score 0):

is possible that the component the solution is looking for is part of the product you need to update:

go in settings -> administration -> Install product updateds at the bottom

that component should contain the relation the solution is looking for.

[image]

No one has the rights to move that component and it will result in an error if you don't have it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The case is now with Microsoft support. I will update here when it will be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the version number the one you are trying to import too has a lower version. You can't import a solution with a version number that is less or equal to the current version installed.

Look in the Solution.xml and find the version node and change it to 6.1.1.1848.

*The import solution must have a higher version than the existing solution it is upgrading.*